# Junit: determine junit is running or not

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, junit4

is there Junit.isRunning() is junit framework, for instance:

```
public void m() {
    if (Junit.isRunning()) {
       // load little test data 
    } else {
        // load large real data
    }
}
```

**my question is:** how to determine current env is test stage or not(like rails ENV['RAILS_ENV'] == 'test')

Comment: This seems like a bad idea - it couples your production code to your test framework. Why can't the test framework instruct the code what dataset it should load?

Comment: @DNA but if real data is large, i use test data in test stage will faster

Comment: Yes, that's fine - the point is that your tests should handle that decision. You should generally avoid putting special cases in your actual code to handle testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have commented, this seems a bad idea - because you will be unit testing code that is different to the actual production code.

You could instead use mock data for your tests by utilising a mocking framework like Mockito: http://code.google.com/p/mockito/.

Say you are accessing your data via a simple DAO:

```
public class DAO {

public Data loadData() {

    Data data = null;

    // Load data from database and set in data variable ...

    return data;
}
```

}

Your method under test could then look like:

```
public class MyClass {

private DAO dao;

public void m() {

    dao.loadData();

    // Rest of method ...
}

public void setDao(DAO dao) {
    this.dao = dao;
}
```

}

And your test class:

```
public class MyClassTest {

@Test
public void testM() {

    MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

    DAO mockDAO = mock(DAO.class);
    Data mockData = mock(Data.class);

    when(mockDAO.loadData()).thenReturn(mockData);
    myClass.setDao(mockDAO);

    // Call method under test
    myClass.m();

    // Rest of test ...
}
```

}

Now the method under test will use the mock data during your unit test.

Comment: Thanks, it work well, but i think Junit.isRunning() is necessary, since mockito only redef one class meth, the sub class meth of this class is not

Comment: And i find mockito still need to run full meth, it just change return val

Comment: "As others have commented, this seems a bad idea - because you will be unit testing code that is different to the actual production code." And then you suggest Mockito? You apparently think running a test on a Mockito mock is testing with "actual production code"! If you ask me, using an "isJUnitRunning()" method is by and large safer than patching together a bunch of phony test objects and convincing yourself you've tested production code. At least it's _transparently_ cheating, not elaborately and opaquely cheating.

Comment: @barneypitt This was 8 years ago. These days I am not so keen on mocks, and only use them when strictly necessary. But I stand by the suggestion of dependency injection as the best solution to this problem.

Comment: @RCB Fair enough. I don't think isJUnitRunning() is exactly a fabulous solution! I'm just very wary of overreliance on mock objects. I'm fairly wary of the whole ethos surrounding unit testing, in particular putting any faith in a coverage tool telling you you have "92% of code paths covered". Experience shows again and again that very often production bugs actually _were_ "covered", but that there was an error in the assumptions of the test, or more often simply that edge cases weren't considered. Continued...

Comment: You usually don't know something _is_ an edge case until it becomes a discovered bug. End-to-end testing of real data with real objects from real databases is in many cases far superior to any number of unit tests.